# Arabic Character Codification

Tags: html, character

I don't know why if I got this

لعائلاتكم وزملاءكم ورفاقكم الذين هم في حاجة لمثل هذه الخدمة؟ هل تنصحون ب

in my database, and I can see the same in my backoffice, I see this strange characters in browser:

لعائلاتك� وز�لاءك� ورفاقك� الذين ه� في حاجة ل�ثل هذه الخد�ة؟ هل تنصحون ب

Here is the way I form html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />
```

Comment: There are a number of steps between "my backoffice" and your HTML. What exactly are you doing there? If in doubt, output a hexdump of your strings (e.g. look at your HTML using a hex editor) and figure out and/or tell us what extra bytes there are at these specific characters.

Comment: Thanks. I'm gonna try a hex editor.